# Webpack library function is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack

As the title says, i'm getting an error in the browser `Uncaught TypeError: MYLIB.init is not a function`.

**webpack.config.js**:

As you can see i have set the `library` and `libraryTarget`, which is usually the problem with this.

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'mylib.min.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'MYLIB',
    libraryTarget: 'var'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist/demo',
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/key.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/cert.pem'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
              "plugins": ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js']
  },
};
```

**index.js**:

Here i'm exporting correctly the init function.

```
'use strict';

export function init(provider, options){
  alert('init!');
}
```

**index.html**:

The path to the js file is correct and is found by the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lib Demo</title>

  <script src="../mylib.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    MYLIB.init('bla', {});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack serve --open --host 0.0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.9",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.24.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
```

`npm run build` runs successfully: `webpack 5.24.2 compiled successfully`

then `npm run start`, it opens the browser and i get that error `Uncaught TypeError: MYLIB.init is not a function`.. What am i doing wrong? i have a similar setup that works perfectly fine with older package versions so i'm guessing something changed with webpack and i don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webpack configuration is wrong where you are using babel-loader(plugins will not be inside presets).

Correct:

```
{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env'
                    ],
                    "plugins": ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'], //<--Notice here
                }
},
```

Secondly:

Change the version of webpack dev server as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66045178/10102695) to "^4.0.0-beta.0"
and More Detail on this is [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11887) at github page.

Final Configuration, I checked with:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        mylib: ['./src/index.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'mylib.min.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'MYLIB',
        libraryTarget: 'var'
    },
    devServer: {
        static: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        hot: true,
        port: 3000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env'
                    ],
                    "plugins": [
                        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
                    ],
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js']
    },
};
```

Package Json:

```
    "main": "dist/mylib.min.js",
    "description": "Light Weight Next Generation MAP-Renderer",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "webpack --mode=production",
        "watch": "webpack --watch",
        "start": "webpack serve --mode development --config webpack.config.js"
    },
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.9",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "css-loader": "^5.1.1",
        "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "webpack": "^5.24.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0-beta.0"
    },
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Thanks!